# error in starting server with npm start

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

I am new to nodeJs:

I have written down server.js file, I installed nodejs. when I am running `"npm start"` I am getting following errors.

> C:\Users\server\server.js:43
>   if (!(req.headers &amp;amp;&amp;amp;
>   req.headers.authorization)) {
>
> ```
>                     ^                                                                                                                           SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;                                       
>
> at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)                                                                                                      
> at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)                                                                                                          
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)                                                                                            
> at Module.load (module.js:355:32)                                                                                                              
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)                                                                                                    
> at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)                                                                                                  
> at startup (node.js:129:16)                                                                                                                    
> at node.js:814:3                                                                                                                               
>                                                                                                                                                 npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
> ```
>
> npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "start"
>   npm ERR! node v0.12.4
>   npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! der-server@0.0.0 start: `node server.js`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Failed at the der-server@0.0.0 start script 'node server.js'.
>   npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the der-server package,
>   npm ERR! not with npm itself.
>   npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
>   npm ERR!     node server.js
>   npm ERR! You can get their info via:
>   npm ERR!     npm owner ls der-server
>   npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> ```
>                                                                                                                                                 npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
> ```
>
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\server\npm-debug.log

Answer (score 2):

You code is showing the && as escaped characters. That is not valid JavaScript.